# How are elements in an eRubis document cloned throughout the page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, eruby, erubis

I have a simple eRubis (*.html.erb) document, and want to "copy" various elements throughout a page. Whenever I use simple Ruby statements like this:
`<%= 3.times do %> ... <% end %>` with multiple "times" statements within that to copy more elements returns either errors or horribly rendered elements. What is the best way to "copy" multiple elements throughout a eRubis page using Ruby statements?

Comment: Have you used partials before? This seems to describe exactly the problem they are used to solve

Comment: Of course. The only issue is that you still need a Ruby statement to render that partial multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I use in RoR is `content_for` and `yield`. I store my element(s) in a `content_for` and then I litter `yield`s around wherever I want that element:

```
<% content_for :some_elements do %>
  <divs or whatever />
  <and maybe some things too />
  <%= even some more erb %>
<% end %>

<%= yield :some_elements %>
<%= yield :some_elements %>
<%= yield :some_elements %>
```

Those `yield`s can go anywhere, you could even have the `content_for` in your layout file and put those `yield`s in any view or partial as many times as you want.

If you want to simply mock up a list or something, `times` works perfectly well if you use it correctly:

```
<ul>
  <% 10.times do |i| %>
    <li id="item_#{i}">
      content in item <%= i %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But of course the `times` approach requires that all the elements be in the same spot. That's the advantage of the `content_for`/`yield` way, you can place the `yield`s where ever you want. You can even put a `yield` inside a `times`:

```
<% 10.times do |i| %>
  <%= yield :some_elements %>
<% end %>
```

But that's just crazy. Anyway, have fun.